# Вопрос о hash_equals в функции шифрования

Tags: php, безопасность, openssl

Всем привет!. Столкнулся с проблемой. Взял 2 функции шифрования и дешифрования с одного сайта. Код ниже.

```
    define('ENCRYPTION_KEY', 'ab86d144e3f080b61c7c2e43');

// Encrypt
$plaintext = "Тестируем обратимое шифрование на php 7";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, ENCRYPTION_KEY, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, ENCRYPTION_KEY, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
echo $ciphertext.'<br>';

// Decrypt
$c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, ENCRYPTION_KEY, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, ENCRYPTION_KEY, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))
{
    echo $plaintext;
}
```

Далее привёл их к виду

```
// Encrypt
function encrypt($text,$key)
{

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($text, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
$input = array("=", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "j", "k", "y", "a");
$output   = array("!№", "#", "|", "%", "+", "-", "_", ")", "$", "^", "&:&");
$ciphertext = str_replace($input, $output, $ciphertext);
return $ciphertext;
}
// Decrypt
function decrypt($hash,$key)
{
$input = array("=", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "j", "k", "y", "a");
$output   = array("!№", "#", "|", "%", "+", "-", "_", ")", "$", "^", "&:&");
$hash = str_replace($output, $input, $hash);

$c = base64_decode($hash);
var_dump($c);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
var_dump(hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac));
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))
{

    return $plaintext;

}


}
```

Ключ генерирую следующим образом:

```
function generate()
{
    $chars="0123456789ABCDEF"; 
$max=32; 
$size=StrLen($chars)-1; 
$password=null; 
    while($max--) 
    $password.=$chars[rand(0,$size)]; 
    return $password;
}
```

Собственно в чем вопрос, в функции дешифрования строки есть условие (  hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)  ) , так вот, это условие в моём случае всегда возвращает False. Из-за этого функция ничего не возвращает, но в переменной $plaintext содержится уже расшифрованная строка и расшифрована она верно, но из-за этого условия она не возвращается. И теперь вопрос, почему условие возвращает false и можно ли убрать это условие и продолжить использовать функцию в таком виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что в процессе дополнительного кодирования/раскодирования зашифрованного сообщения Вы его изменяете. Дело в том, что [RFC 4648](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) Base64 кодирования определяет такие символы:

```
                  Table 1: The Base 64 Alphabet

 Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding  Value Encoding
     0 A            17 R            34 i            51 z
     1 B            18 S            35 j            52 0
     2 C            19 T            36 k            53 1
     3 D            20 U            37 l            54 2
     4 E            21 V            38 m            55 3
     5 F            22 W            39 n            56 4
     6 G            23 X            40 o            57 5
     7 H            24 Y            41 p            58 6
     8 I            25 Z            42 q            59 7
     9 J            26 a            43 r            60 8
    10 K            27 b            44 s            61 9
    11 L            28 c            45 t            62 +
    12 M            29 d            46 u            63 /
    13 N            30 e            47 v
    14 O            31 f            48 w         (pad) =
    15 P            32 g            49 x
    16 Q            33 h            50 y
```

А Ваш дополнительный кодировщик тоже использует замену на `+`. Отсюда и проблема, причем она плавающая, зависящая был ли в Base64 тексте + или нет.

Исправьте, например так:

```
//                                     vvv
$output   = array("!№", "#", "|", "%", "@", "-", "_", ")", "$", "^", "&:&");
```

Вот рабочий пример на [ideone](https://ideone.com/wbSKPC)